# With Python3 & Stomp, how to disable prefetch of activemq?

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp, prefetch

I'm designing a distributed project, on win10. However all messages goes to one consumer with below code. It caches all before handling them. What is the correct way to to that?

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
import stomp
import time

#http://localhost:8161 

queue_name = '/queue/SampleQueue'
topic_name = '/topic/SampleTopic'
listener_name = 'SampleListener'

class SampleListener(object):
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print ('headers: %s' % headers)
        print ('message: %s' % message)
        time.sleep(1) # blocking consumer here

def send_to_queue(msg):
    conn = stomp.Connection10([('127.0.0.1',61613)])
    conn.start()
    conn.connect()
    for i in range(50):
        conn.send(queue_name, msg)
    conn.disconnect()

def receive_from_queue():
    conn = stomp.Connection10([('127.0.0.1',61613)])
    conn.set_listener(listener_name, SampleListener())
    conn.start()
    conn.connect()
    #conn.subscribe(queue_name, {'ack': 'client-individual', 'activemq.prefetchSize': 0})
    conn.subscribe(queue_name, {'activemq.prefetchSize':1, })

    time.sleep(600) # secs
    conn.disconnect()


if __name__=='__main__':
    if True:
        send_to_queue('sample text 123')
        receive_from_queue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, I used ActiveMQ and stompy (I know it's a different module or probably an older version of the module) and I had the same prefetching problem and I worked around it by setting ack='client' in the subscribe call: `stomp.subscribe(SETTINGS.QUEUE, ack='client')`

Looking at the [docs](https://stomppy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#stomp.protocol.Protocol12.subscribe), you should be able to do the same with the module you are using.

Here's part of my old code:

```
from stompy.simple import Client

destination = 'yourqueuehere'
settings = {} # some dictionary with the host, port, etc.; I forget exactly

stomp = Client(**settings)
stomp.connect()
stomp.subscribe(destination, ack='client')
try:
    while True:
        message = stomp.get()
        stomp.ack(message) # I have to call ack myself since I have ack='client' above
        # do something with message

finally:    
    stomp.unsubscribe(destination)
    stomp.disconnect()
```

I forgot what went in `settings`.

Comment: Thanks, but still not work. I did so: 
updated subscribe as below:
receive_from_queue():
    conn.subscribe(queue_name, id=taskname, ack='client')

, and updated on_message as below:
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        self.conn.ack(headers['message-id'], self.taskname)
        ........

Comment: With ack=client, all message are pending, and conn.ack is not working at all. By deleting the queue, I can see the program continue receving messages. Crazy!

Comment: I notice that you are passing a `dict` to the `subscribe` method: `conn.subscribe(queue_name, {'activemq.prefetchSize':1, })`. Where is that documented? The subscribe meethod in the doc I saw has this signature: `subscribe(destination, id, ack='auto', headers=None, **keyword_headers)`

Comment: Yes, a typo mistake. should be headers={'activemq.prefetchSize':1, }